# Upload files to SharePoint Online as System Account

Tags: powershell, office365, sharepoint-online

How do I **upload files** and **create folders** to SharePoint Online through PowerShell while keeping their metadata (Modified By) as **"System Account"** instead of having the files using my account on the metadata?

I know I can change the metadata for files by doing this:

```
$user = Get-PnPUser -ErrorAction Stop | ? Email -eq $email 

$newFile["Author"]   = $user.id
$newFile["Editor"]   = $user.id
$newFile["Modified"] = $currentFile.LastWriteTimeUtc
$newFile["Created"]  = $currentFile.CreationTimeUtc

$newFile.Update()
```

But how about folders? If I use CSOM with PowerShell (see below) I can't find a way to modify the metadata properties for "Author" and "Editor":

```
$CSOM_credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($cred.UserName, $cred.Password)
$CSOM_context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://tenanturl.sharepoint.com")
$CSOM_context.Credentials = $CSOM_credentials

$ParentFolder = $CSOM_context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Samples")

$newFolder = $ParentFolder.Folders.Add("New Folder")
$ParentFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()

$CSOM_context.Load($newFolder)
$CSOM_context.ExecuteQuery()
```

If I use the PnP PowerShell **(Add-PnPFolder)**, I have the same problem I can't get a way to modify the same metadata

Comment: Would you be able to use a 'service account' to perform the task instead?

Comment: how do I do that? we are talking about SPO not SP on-prem, could elaborate? I.m not sure if I follow

Comment: You would need to have an account created in Office365 to be used as a service account, then use those credentials to connect to SPO prior to running your SPO commands. Have you got any code you can share that we can help with?

Comment: Can you please share the code within your question, that you are having a problem with, based on information in this blog - https://www.petri.com/upload-files-entire-file-shares-metadata-sharepoint-online

Comment: I know the trick of keeping metadata for files, but to be more precise, how to keep the metadata for everything, including folders, the solution you mentioned doesn't cover the problem with folders, I will update my question with an example

Comment: Folder object for SPO is documented here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder_members.aspx

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a Member property for the creator of the folder, but it may exist in one of the other members and you may be able to overwrite that data. You will need to investigate this further - whatever the case, it is not documented. I also don't think it really matters who created the folder, but you may be able to get it to work.

Comment: I know this MSDN article, and it is bad as it gets without any further documentation. On my own I've been trying to use ListItemAllFields.FieldValues - so far I could get the values but no much luck editing the properties, thanks Adam, it seems we have been there :)

Comment: That's a real shame! Maybe it's worth raising a request with the team at their Github repo - https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell

Comment: thanks Adam! you've been a true partner helping me as much as you could! i'll keep investigating further, hopefully I will come back to post a solution or somebody will :D

Comment: No problem, that would be great. If I had an O365 lab then I may have been more help :/ sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SHAREPOINT\System" to set Author and Editor to System Account.

```
$Id = 1024
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List "listNmae" -Id $Id
Set-PnPListItem -List "listNmae" -Identity $Id -Values @{"Author" = "SHAREPOINT\System";
"Editor" = "SHAREPOINT\System";
"Modified" = $item.FieldValues.Modified 
}
```

Also you can get System Account user using

```
$sysaccount = Get-PnPUser | ? {$_.LoginName -eq "SHAREPOINT\System"}
```